# When using jquery-validate, how do I add a custom validate function that applies to the entire form?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-validate, customization

I know that you can add custom validation functions for specific elements by doing something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('>0', function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value) > 0;
}, 'Amount needs to be greater than 0');
```

But I am wondering if there is a way I can add a custom validate function across the entire form. First I'll give you the reason why I need this. In my form I have about 40 select fields with percentages in them. I require them to add up to 100. I can't add a custom function to figure this out because these select fields represent categories which are constantly changing (out of my power).

Here is a function that I have written that if I could somehow just run this function as part of the validation it would work.

```
var answer = false;

var categories = $('select').find('option:selected:not([value="0"])').parent();
var percent = 0;
$.each(categories, function(i, category){
    percent += +$(category).val();
});
if(percent == 100){
    $('#percentage-error').html("");
    answer = true;
}else{
    alert("Percentages must add up to 100%.");
    $('#percentage-error').html("PERCENTAGES MUST ADD UP TO 100%");
}

return answer;
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="cat_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Artisan Food</td>
            <td>
                <select name="31">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Home Decor - Wood Carvings</td>
            <td>
                <select name="24">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bath &amp; Body</td>
            <td>
                <select name="1">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Home Decor - Woodcraft</td>
            <td>
                <select name="25">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ceramics/Porcelain</td>
            <td>
                <select name="3">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Jewelry</td>
            <td>
                <select name="9">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fine Art</td>
            <td>
                <select name="5">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Leather</td>
            <td>
                <select name="11">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Functional Pottery</td>
            <td>
                <select name="7">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Music</td>
            <td>
                <select name="13">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Home Decor - Baby</td>
            <td>
                <select name="2">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Textile Usables</td>
            <td>
                <select name="15">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Home Decor - Dolls</td>
            <td>
                <select name="4">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Textile Usables - Baby</td>
            <td>
                <select name="19">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Home Decor - Embroidery</td>
            <td>
                <select name="6">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Textile Usables - Bags</td>
            <td>
                <select name="17">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Home Decor - Floral</td>
            <td>
                <select name="8">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Textile Usables - Leather</td>
            <td>
                <select name="16">
                    <option value="0">0%</option>
                    <option value="5">5%</option>
                    <option value="10">10%</option>
                    <option value="15">15%</option>
                    <option value="20">20%</option>
                    <option value="25">25%</option>
                    <option value="30">30%</option>
                    <option value="35">35%</option>
                    <option value="40">40%</option>
                    <option value="45">45%</option>
                    <option value="50">50%</option>
                    <option value="55">55%</option>
                    <option value="60">60%</option>
                    <option value="65">65%</option>
                    <option value="70">70%</option>
                    <option value="75">75%</option>
                    <option value="80">80%</option>
                    <option value="85">85%</option>
                    <option value="90">90%</option>
                    <option value="95">95%</option>
                    <option value="100">100%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice that the names of the selects are numbers. These numbers correspond to the id of the category in the database. An admin can turn on and off these categories and add or remove them at any time.

So any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can you show up some HTML, I still cannot imagine the situation :(

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe, Ok I added a portion of the HTML.

Comment: use `addMethod` with your code in it and apply to last `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `addMethod` with your code in it and apply to last select :

```
$.validator.addMethod('select_total_precent', function(value, element){
    /* your select percentage validation code here*/

      return answer;
}, 'Amount needs to be greater than 0');


$('#formID').validate();
/* must initialize validation before adding rules*/
$('#formID').find('select:last').rules('add', {select_total_precent:true})
```

Would help user a lot if you provided a viewable total as they change selects. If you did that you could validate that field instead of your approach and simply disable it prior to submit in the `submitHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Call your function to check the percentage in the submitHandler function.  This will get called when the rest of the form is valid